# Changers like (if:) need to be combined using + between them

Tags: javascript, twine-game-engine

I'm using Twine to try and make a simple game, and I need an if statement that checks a number variable and a Boolean

The code looks like this:

> (if:$money >=20)(if:$BPV is false)[[Buy some armor]]

And Twine outputs this when I try and play the game:

> Changers like (if:) need to be combined using + between them.

If I change the code to this:

> (if:$money >=20 + $BPV is false)[[Buy some armor]]

It doesn't display the "Buy some armor" part

Trying:

> (if:$money >=20 + $BPV is 0)[[Buy some armor]]

Also doesn't display the "Buy some armor" part

What can I do?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but did you try writing the word `and` instead of the symbol `+`?

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have:

```
(if:$money >=20 + $BPV is false)[[Buy some armor]]
```

Normally when you're linking commands up, you put the plus between them like this:

```
(if:$money >= 20)+(if:$BPV is false)[Buy some armor]
```